# How to see RAM usage from processes that don't appear in the Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, memory, process

I know that not all processes appear in the Task Manager. However, I am curious about the complete breakdown of my RAM usage, so I would like to view the RAM usage of all processes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Sysinternals will help you to find the RAM usage.

[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) will display all Processes and Sub-Processes with their usage. You should start the Process Explorer as admin to see system wide processes.

Process Explorer will not show the locked RAM eg. "driver locked". This you can see in [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap). "Driver locked" RAM is most likely if you have virtualisation like Hyper-V.